# xl2tpd[845]: parse_config: line 13: data 'ipsec sared=yes' occurs with no context

Tags: ipsec, openswan

When I executed xl2tpd I amhaving following error.

```
# xl2tpd -D
xl2tpd[845]: parse_config: line 13: data 'ipsec sared=yes' occurs with no context
xl2tpd[845]: init: Unable to load config file
```

When I remove the "line 13" I having same error with "Line 14" thefore I do not think that the problem is about "ipsec sared"
Here is my configuration file xl2tpd.conf.

LINUX Ubuntu 12.0.4 ;Openswan IPsec 2.6.37; xl2tpd version:  xl2tpd-1.3.1

```
; [global]                                                             
 ipsec sared=yes
 listen-addr=47.168.137.27

; [lns default]
 ip range = 192.168.1.10-192.168.1.20
 local ip = 192.168.1.1
 require chap = yes
 refuse pap = yes
 require authentication = yes
 ppp debug = yes
 pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd
 length bit = yes
 name=LinuxIPSECVPN
```

ANSWER:(since have not enough reputation I am writting it over here.)
removing the ";" character at the beginning of [global] and [lns default] have solved the issue.
At fist I tought that [global] and[lns default] were just a comment.

Comment: removing the ";" character at the beginning of [global] and [lns default] have solved the issue.
At fist I tought that [global] and[lns default] were just a comment.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is, that you have correct this line in this way:

```
ipsec shared=yes
```

EDIT:

According [for example this URL](http://rootmanager.com/ubuntu-ipsec-l2tp-windows-domain-auth/setting-up-openswan-xl2tpd-with-native-windows-clients.html) it's not `shared`, but `saref`. Then you have correct this line:

```
ipsec saref=yes
```

Comment: This was another problem that I realized after solving first one that I shred. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I missed @mmc18's comment for a while so I'm posting it here as an answer for others:

> Removing the ";" character at the beginning of [global] and [lns
>   default] have solved the issue. At fist I tought that [global] and
>   [lns default] were just a comment.

I edited this file by hand and didn't notice the comments before the sections either.